# A question on linear programming problem (operation research)

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

Suppose we want to solve the following lpp:

> Min $C^T x$ subject to $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, $C$ is in $R^n$ and $b$ in $R^m$. Show that if there exists $x$ in $R^n$ with $Ax=b$ and the minimum value is finite (i.e. there is a lower bound) then $C^Tx=k$ ($k$ is a constant) for all solutions $Ax=b$.

How should I proceed? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Try proving the contrapositive: if the problem is feasible but the objective value is not constant, then the problem is unbounded.